# FindControl always returns null on dynamically generated table

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a generated table using the following code (snippet):

```
String sTable = "<table id=\"ediTable\" runat=\"server\">\n" +
         "...\n" +
         "</table>\n";
table_display.InnerHtml = sTable;
table_win.Style.Add("display", "block");//show table
```

I then, later in my code, try to find this table using the `FindControl()` method to find this table as follows:

```
protected void SubmitTable(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    Control ctrl = table_display.FindControl("ediTable");
}
```

Here is my relevant html:

```
...
<div id="table_display" runat="server">
</div>
<asp:Button ID="submitReport" CssClass="submit_btn" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="SubmitTable" />
...
```

`ctrl` is always null when I step through my code, despite the fact that table_display still contains the html table. I know I could use a `DataList`, `DataView` or `Repeater` to generate the table instead, but I don't know how to use them and would rather get this working instead. 
If it's not possible to use `FindControl` this way, then I will just go and figure them out.

Comment: Your control ediTable simply doesn't exist as such... you're not adding a control, you're putting content in html content. Best proff is you will be able to see the "runat" attribute in your HTML source ,while you shouldn't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to use `FindControl` like that. `InnerHtml` won't be parsed, converted to web control instances and added to control tree so your table will never be found.

Comment: Thank you. I had suspected as much. I will mark this as the answer in 9 minutes.